# Converting elements of a list based on corresponding dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have tried googling this but the google results just tell me how to convert a list into a dictionary, which is not what I want to do.

I have a list: `colors = ['Red', 'White', 'Green', 'Red']`

and I have a dictionary: `color_dict = {'Red': 0, 'White': 1, 'Green': 2}`

I want to end up with `converted_colors = [0, 1, 2, 0]`

I have tried `converted_colors = [color for colors in color_dict[color]]` and `converted_colors = [color for color_dict[color] in colors]`

but both give the same error `NameError: name color is not defined`

Is my approach all wrong?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example

```py
converted_colors = [color_dict[color] for color in colors]
```

Here the output

```
[0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought I might be close.

Comment: You were close!

Answer (score 1):

This is another alternative way of doing it

```
colors = ['Red', 'White', 'Green', 'Red']
color_dict = {'Red': 0, 'White': 1, 'Green': 2}
converted_colors = []

for i in colors:
    converted_colors.append(color_dict[i])
print(converted_colors)
```